# Ruby on Rails: Select all id's except one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, request

I want to select all ids except the first. 
User.find(:all) calls all ids, but how can i make an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Via single query:

```
User.offset(1).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: I want to add .tasks.name, so I get all tasks from all users except user_id 1

Comment: You could then do something like this: User.offset(1).map{|u| u.tasks.pluck(:name)}.flatten.compact

Answer (score 0):

Will give you all ids except first one

```
User.where(:_id.ne => User.first.id).map(&:_id)
```

Comment: This seems to mix AREL and ActiveRecord query methods. Unfortunately, I found no documentation (or code) of how this could work and couldn't make it to work on my testbed either. Do you have any links to further documentation on this?